# javascript regex validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have declared this regex at the top of my js file -

```
var regexName = /^[ A-Za-z]+$/
```

Futher down I have a validate function - it fires on Page submit but also on keyup function for certain textboxes on the page.

```
$('#Name).keyup(function () { validateContactDetails(); });
```

This is my function:

```
function validateContactDetails() {

    var errorText = "";
    var valid = true;

    $("#ValidationHolder").text(errorText);

    var Name= $('#Name');

    Name.removeClass("input-validation-error");

        if ( isEmpty(Name.val()) || Name.val().length > 40  && !regexName.test(Name.val()) ) {

            Name.addClass("input-validation-error");

            errorText += "Name cannot  be empty or longer than 40 letters or contain numbers. ";

            valid = false;
        }

$("#ValidationHolder").html(errorText);

    return valid;
}
```

I then include this js file in my cshtml page.  However the regex validation isnt working at the minute - it is letting me enter numbers in the Name textbox on the page.  Anyone see something simple I have missed?

Comment: You've got missing closing quotes on your `$('#Name..` calls.

Comment: a that was just a copy paste error - checked the code file and they are there.

Comment: You can use `/^\w+$/i` instead of your `/^[ A-Za-z]+$/`.

Comment: @webbandit: No, you can not. He does not want to match digits or underscore.

Comment: think I may have it -I missed a ; on my regex declaration - well Im hoping that is it - just going to test now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was checking for && condition instead od || condition which was the problem here as well as missing the ; in my regex